# jQuery - Select <option> and Trigger .on("change") on Page Reload

Tags: jquery

I have an inventory page that has HTML with this `<select>` powered filter:

```
    <select id="filter">
      <option value="Master Inventory">Master Inventory</option>
      <option value="Pottery">Pottery</option>
      <option value="Incense">Incense</option>
      <option value="Other Items">Other Items</option>
    </select>
```

When the users select an `option` in the filter, it reads the all of the items in the `table` and hides the ones that don't have the matching item type. It does this using the following code:

```
$("#filter").on("change", function () {
  var filterSel = $(this).val();

  if (filterSel !== "Master Inventory") {
    var f = 0;

    while (f <= ($('tr[item]').last().attr("item"))) {
      if ($('tr[item="' + f + '"]').attr("type") !== filterSel) {
        $('tr[item="' + f + '"]').hide(500);
        }
      else {
        $('tr[item="' + f + '"]').show(500);
        }

      f = f + 1;
      }
    }
  else {
    var g = 0;

    while (g <= ($('tr[item]').last().attr("item"))) {
      $('tr[item="' + g + '"]').show(500);

      g = g + 1;
      }
    }
  });
```

Some of the functions on the page cause it to refresh (usually when an item is modified or updated), and I've written in some jQuery that reads the current filter selection and saves it to `localStorage`. When the page loads, it checks to see if there is something in that particular storage unit, and then loads it in. I've got it working so that it changes what the filter says, but it doesn't trigger the `.on("change")` event for the filter itself. This is the code that sets the new `option` for the filter:

```
  curCat = localStorage.getItem("curCat");
  localStorage.setItem("curCat", "none");

  if (curCat !== "none") {
    $("#filter").find(':selected').prop('selected', false);
    $("#filter").find('option[value="' + curCat + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    $("option[value=" + curCat + "]").
    }
  else {
    }
```

How do I get the `select` filter to update *and* trigger the `.on("change")` when the page is reloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the value on the `<select>` itself  after you create the `on('change')` and then trigger the event

```js
const storedValue = 'Incense';

const $sel = $("#filter").on("change", function() {
  console.log('Change triggered, value =', this.value)
});

$sel.val(storedValue).change()// or .trigger('change')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filter">
  <option value="Master Inventory" >Master Inventory</option>
  <option value="Pottery" selected>Pottery</option>
  <option value="Incense">Incense</option>
  <option value="Other Items">Other Items</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly!
_(I ended up using .trigger("change") for anyone who's curious)_